column identification in python dataframe
Is it possible to pass a column list and check if it exists in df.columns, then keep those column and drop others ?
col_list = ['Name of Company','Incorporated','Country']

I have a dataframe df2 like below-
|Name|Country|Nature of business|Shares held by the Group|Shares held by NCI|
|Directly held interests|NaN|NaN|NaN|NaN|
|Ferrari S.p.A.|Italy|Manufacturing|100%|-%|
|Indirectly held through Ferrari S.p.A.|NaN|NaN|NaN|NaN|

I need those columns in the dataframe which is present in col_list and each row as json.
Expected output for df2, remove the field having NaN values -
{"Name":"Directly held interests"}
{"Name":"Ferrari S.p.A.","Country":"Italy"}
{"Name of Company":"Indirectly held through Ferrari S.p.A."}

Any help would be appreciated.

Yes, exactly as how you would find the difference between two collections. set.intersection() on the two column lists (converted to sets) would tell you exactly what you want to reduce the columns down to

can you provide the solution?

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3], 
                   'B': [4, 5, 6], 
                   'C': [7, 8, 9], 
                   'D': [10, 11, 12]})

column_list = ['A', 'C', 'E']

def filter_columns(df, column_list, in_place=False):
    available_columns = [col for col in column_list if col in df.columns]
    
    if not available_columns:
        return pd.DataFrame()

    if in_place:
        df.drop(columns=[col for col in df.columns if col not in available_columns], inplace=True)
        return df
    else:
        filtered_df = df[available_columns].copy()
        return filtered_df

result_df = filter_columns(df, column_list, True)
result_df.dropna(inplace=True)
json_output = result_df.to_json(orient='records')
print(json_output)


is it possible to drop the NaN values from json as expected output ?

@emiley mille - I edited my answer to include a line to drop rows with NA values, in-place.

I don't want to remove the nan rows , but in the json nan field should not exist and other field can exist
